# Formatting Availble Values list SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am looking to format a parameter that is a drop down of available values. The format I am looking for is ###-####-###.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend in the SQL procedure you are using as the data set for the parameter to format the values there.  This would be the easiest way to format the values you have if you always want to format the field value.

Otherwise you can add a calculated field to the data set and use that as your Label for the parameter.  This will allow you to format the Label of the field but keep the Value different.

For instance in my data set GetPhoneNo, I added a field called PhoneNoFormat which is equal to =FORMAT(Fields!PhoneNo.Value, (###)###-####").  I then set the available values for my PhoneNo in my project to PhoneNoFormat rather than PhoneNo.